# different ways of declaring and defining a variable in java

Tags: java, arrays

I know that if you want to declare an array in Java you should use syntax like:

```
class Dog {
    Dog[] pets = new Dog[7];
}
```

but I saw another format in "Head First Java" (p83) that Eclipse gives me a syntax error for:

```
class Dog {
    Dog[] pets;
    pets = new Dog[7];
}
```

Could somebody please explain the reason?
Thanks

Comment: Show the exact code from `Head First Java`.

Comment: /*
Declare and create a Dog array,
to hold 7 Dog references.
Dog[] pets;
pets = new Dog[7]; */

Comment: Does it show that code directly in a `class` body?

Comment: The initialization can be done inside a method not directly in the class body

Comment: thanks guys, I think I should use it in the main, not directly in class

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, the examples using this start on page 59, and I checked, it does not show it like above.

Comment: Always post the *exact* error message you're getting. You should learn to read them and understand what they say if you want to learn a new language.

Comment: Tnx @WIllJBD but it is in page #83

Comment: @Aaron in the index of 2nd edition (you didn't specify which one) look at arrays -> assignment it says page 59, which is where it starts. The particular code you reference is pages 60,61,62, and 83 as well. I did say it starts on 59, and regardless it doesn't show it like you had it.

Comment: @Aaron well I hate to have to point out how wrong you are but `class Dog { Dog[] pets; pets = new Dog[7]; }` clearly does not equal `Dog[] pets;
    pets = new Dog[7];` no where in the book did it show the array being declared separately, and then allocated within the class body outside of a function. If you can not comprehend this simple unequivocal comparison then perhaps you need far more help than can be provided. Why you would ask for help over such a simple, trivial,  noobish error and then blame the book, and argue you are right when you are wrong, is childish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your example doesn't make any sense. Why would a `Dog` have other pet dogs? Let's go with `Human` instead, shall we?

---

```
class Human {
   Dog[] pets = new Dog[7];   // Note that I fixed your code, by declaring
                              // this as an **array** of Dog
}
```

This is a *class member declaration*. You're declaring a public array of `Dog`, and *also* initializing it.  For all intents and purposes, the following example is equivalent. I am initializing `pets` in the *constructor*.

```
class Human {
   Dog[] pets;

   public Human() {
      pets = new Dog[7];
   }
}
```

---

However, this is invalid:

```
class Human {
   Dog[] pets;
   pets = new Dog[7];    // Cannot include executable statements outside
                         // the context of a function.
}
```

All code (executable statements) must be inside a function. You can't just put code in a class.

Perhaps what you're confusing that for, is something like this:

```
class Program {
    void main() {
        Dog[] pets;

        pets = new Dog[7];
    }
}
```

This is acceptable, because `pets` is a *local variable*, defined only in the scope of the `main` function.

Comment: Yes! I agree with you about this but I just wanted to state exact example from the book: http://up.liz.ir/f/6995-Selection_002.jpg
and thanks for clear explanation

Comment: @Aaron That example should be taken with a grain of salt, because it has no context. The code you've pointed out is *only* valid in the context of a *function*.